# Problema al escribir comillas en HTML

Tags: html, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente código HTML de un ImageButton.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:DataList ID="dlImagenes" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" HorizontalAlign="Center" PagedControlID="dlImagenes">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgValidarImagenes" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="150px" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("imagen") %>' OnClick='<%# "popImage('" + Bind("imagen") + "', Validar imagen)"%>' CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' />
             </ItemTemplate>                                                                                                    
       </asp:DataList>
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dlImagenes"/>
     </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Y tengo el siguiente error:

> error de ASP.NET en tiempo de ejecución: Se debe asignar una llamada a Bind a una propiedad de un control dentro de una plantilla.
>   Creo que se debe a que están mal puestas las comillas en la propiedad de la función popImage del evento onClick.
>   Intenté de varias formas pero sigo sin encontrar la forma correcta de escribirlo.
>   Los siguientes son los código que no me dieron resultado:

```
OnClick='popImage('<%# Bind(\"imagen\") %>', Validar imagen)'

OnClick='popImage('<%# Bind(&quot;imagen&quot;) %>', Validar imagen)'
```

Puede ser que esté abordando mal el problema?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el bindeo no es correcto. Cuando haces el binding de un atributo tenes que hacer el binding del atributo completo. En esto `<%# %>` se comporta distinto al `<%= %>` (que es un Response.Write).

Por otro lado tenes que user la property [OnClientClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx).

La forma correcta de hacer el bind es:

```
OnClientClick='<%# "popImage('" + Bind("imagen") + "', 'Validar imagen')"%>'
```

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Puede compartir un poco más de tu markup?

Comment: Listo, fijate que edité el HTML en la pregunta

Comment: Por que no usas Eval?

Comment: Te referís a que use Eval para pasar el parámetro a la función?

Comment: Hacer `OnClick='<%# "popImage('" + Eval("imagen") + "', Validar imagen)"%>'`

Comment: El problema con este código es que me toma literalmente todo el string y no está concatenando el valor "imagen". Es como si lo escribiera asi: ``"popImage( + Eval(imagen) + , Validar imagen)"``

Comment: Lo escribí asi: ``"popImage("Bind("imagen") + ", Validar imagen)"`` y me dice que falta el punto y coma ``;``

Comment: Ahi cambié la respuesta. La property que deberías usar es OnClientClick

Comment: Me sigue indicando que falta el ``;``

Comment: Si el error es en Javascript faltaban las commilas en `'Validar imagen'`